# Canada Express Entry: Authorised to work?

Tags: canada, express-entry

I am applying for Express Entry to Canada, therefore I am also looking for a job there to increase my points and sustain myself when I move there.

Many job applications ask "Are you legally authorized to work in the country of the work location".  As I do not yet have a work visa or PR, I'm cannot legally work in Canada yet.  But if I get a job, I will qualify for PR.

How do I approach and solve this chicken-egg situation where I need a job to get PR and I need PR to get a job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An outland application for Express Entry unfortunately doesn't confer work authorization in Canada. So you will need to answer no to that question.

You're right that having a job offer gives you additional points towards your express entry profile and make it more likely that you'll be picked up in a draw. Without a job offer, you have to maximize your points from other sources like your language test results or foreign work experience.

Finding a job depends on what industry you're in, if you are in Tech then there is a lot of demand these days.
One strategy could be to find an employer who will sponsor a Closed Work Permit for you, to move to Canada then after a year use this Canadian work experience to get additional points. Another option is to do an intra company transfer from your Home country to Canada for the same employer that you currently work with. This is obviously contingent on your employer having a presence in Canada and the management be willing to move you across borders.